# RSpec: Validate the current subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, subdomain

I use ActsAsTenant to apply multi-tenancy to my application. I check the subdomain whenever before each request by checking if the current tenant is `nil` or not. If the current tenant is `nil`, I redirect the user to the 404 page:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:client, :account_name)

  before_filter :check_subdomain

  private

  def check_subdomain
    redirect_to("/404.html") if ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.nil?
  end
end
```

I have the following spec to test this behaviour:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do

  let(:client) { create(:client) }

  before(:each) do
    @request.host = "#{client.account_name}.lvh.me"
  end

  describe "GET 'new'" do
    context "for invalid subdomains" do
      it "should redirect the user to the 404 page" do
        @request.host = "foo.lvh.me"
        response.should redirect_to "/404.html"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The spec fails with the following error message:

```
F

Failures:

  1) SessionsController GET 'new' for invalid subdomains should redirect the user to the 404 page
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to "/404.html"
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.2098 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:13 # SessionsController GET 'new' for invalid subdomains should redirect the user to the 404 page
```

My question is: Why?? Why does this spec fails? I tried to test it manually from the browser and it worked properly.

Comment: BTW, absolutely awesome question formatting! I SO wish more people asked questions like this. Its SICCO! Specific, Informative, Concise, and On-topic! Good on you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might have the same problem, don't forget to do a request before testing the response!!!!! ie: add `get :new`